# How to get all the questions asked by a specific user from the Stack Exchange API?

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, stackexchange-api

I'm trying to get all the questions with details from Stack Exchange API for a given user ID using following code:

```
response = requests.get("http://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/users/2593236/questions?")
```

However, I receive this error message.

```
{"error_id":400,"error_message":"site is required","error_name":"bad_parameter"}
```

Can anyone help me with this issue and retrieve all user asked questions according to their user ID?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To download all questions or answers from a specific user and stack, you can use:

```
import requests, traceback, json

all_items = []
user = 2593236
stack = "stackoverflow.com"
qa = "questions" # or answers

page = 1
while 1:
    u = f"https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/users/{user}/{qa}?site={stack}&page={page}&pagesize=100"
    j = requests.get(u).json()
    if j:

        all_items += j["items"]

        if not j['has_more']:
            print("No more Pages")
            break
        elif not j['quota_remaining']:
            print("No Quota Remaining ")
            break
    else:
        print("No Questions")
        break

    page+=1


if all_items:
    print(f"How many {qa}? ", len(all_items))
    # save questions/answers to file
    with open(f"{user}_{qa}_{stack}.json", "w") as f:
        f.write(json.dumps(all_items))
```

[Demo](https://trinket.io/python3/d31ee617ed)

Comment: Some suggestions: Increase the page size from the default 30 to 100 (add `&pagesize=100`). That will reduce the number of API calls. Also, should have a way to handle API errors/[backoffs](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/throttle).

Comment: @double-beep I added you suggestion to the answer and demo, tks!

Answer (score 0):

The error message is pretty clear: you have to include a `site` parameter, as explained in [the documentation](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs):

> Each of these methods operates on a single site at a time, identified by the `site` parameter. This parameter can be the full domain name (ie. "stackoverflow.com"), or a short form identified by `api_site_parameter` on the site object.

Try

```
http://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/users/2593236/questions?site=stackoverflow.com
```